# Why does Scala see more lines in a file?

Tags: scala, file-io

Running this from the terminal prompt:

```
$ wc data.csv
195727 15924341 201584826 data.csv
```

So, 195727 lines. What about Scala?

```
val raw_rows: Iterator[String] = scala.io.Source.fromFile("data.csv").getLines()
println(raw_rows.length)
```

Result: 200945

What am I facing here? I wish for it to be the same. In fact, if I use mighty csv (opencsv wrapper lib) it also reads 195727 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a newline issue. From the doc of `getLines`

> Returns an iterator who returns lines (NOT including newline character(s)). It will treat any of \r\n, \r, or \n as a line separator (longest match) - if you need more refined behavior you can subclass Source#LineIterator directly

Comment: It may well be a newline issue but according to the doc you quote, it should happily accept all likely line endings and so would give the same result as wc? (unless the file has \r only line endings as well as others, maybe)

Comment: So basically that's it, in the CSV I have linebreaks within a field surrounded by ""'s, which means wc seems to be smarter.

Same with the CSV library I'm using, also smarter.

Too bad the CSV isn't smart enough to give me access to the raw data it has parsed from. : /